# Php that generates XML

Tags: php, xml, phpmyadmin

```
<?php

require("phpsqlajax_dbinfo.php");
$dom  = new DOMDocument("1.0");
$dp   = fopen('samp.xml', 'w');
$node = $dom->createElement("Groceries");
fwrite($dp, '$node');
$parnode = $dom->appendChild($node);

$connection = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
if (!$connection) {
    die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $connection);
if (!$db_selected) {
    die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysql_error());
}

$query  = "SELECT * FROM tbl_groceryitem";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

echo "<groceries>";
while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    $node = $dom->createElement("item");
    echo "<echo>";
    fwrite($dp, '$node');
    $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);
    $newnode->setAttribute("auto_id", $row['auto_id']);
    echo "<auto_id>", $row[auto_id];
    fwrite($dp, '$newnode');
    $newnode->setAttribute("Gro_barcode", $row['Gro_barcode']);
    echo "<Gro_barcode>", $row[Gro_barcode];
    fwrite($dp, '$newnode');
    $newnode->setAttribute("Gro_name", $row['Gro_name']);
    echo "<Gro_name>", $row[Gro_name];
    fwrite($dp, '$newnode');
    $newnode->setAttribute("Gro_brand", $row['Gro_brand']);
    echo "<Gro_brand>", $row[Gro_brand];
    fwrite($dp, '$newnode');
    $newnode->setAttribute("Gro_category", $row['Gro_category']);
    echo "<Gro_category>", $row[Gro_category];
    fwrite($dp, '$newnode');
    $newnode->setAttribute("Gro_aisle", $row['Gro_aisle']);
    echo "<Gro_category>", $row[Gro_aisle];
    fwrite($dp, '$newnode');
    $newnode->setAttribute("Gro_qty", $row['Gro_qty']);
    echo "<Gro_qty>", $row[Gro_qty];
    fwrite($dp, '$newnode');
    $newnode->setAttribute("Gro_netwt", $row['Gro_netwt']);
    echo "<Gro_netwt>", $row[Gro_netwt];
    fwrite($dp, '$newnode');
    $newnode->setAttribute("Gro_pic", $row['Gro_pic']);
    echo "<Gro_pic>", $row[Gro_pic];
    fwrite($dp, '$newnode');
    $newnode->setAttribute("Gro_price", $row['Gro_price']);
    echo "<Gro_price>", $row[Gro_price];
    fwrite($dp, '$newnode');
    $newnode->setAttribute("Gro_tax", $row['Gro_tax']);
    echo "<Gro_tax>", $row[Gro_tax];
    fwrite($dp, '$newnode');
    echo "</item>";
    fwrite($dp, '</item>');
}
fwrite($dp, '</groceries');
echo $dom->saveXML($xml);

?>
```

I'm new in php.

I'm creating a php file that can generate xml file with data from myPHPAdmin. Thanks :D. Hope someone can help me.

At first try, the code has been displayed in php and when I open to check for the created XML. the display was '`$node`', it reflects the exact string a place inside fwrite, when I try to delete the string quote ('') like this  `fwrite($dp,$node);`. I got error.

And when I try to return the code to  fwrite($dp,'$node');. There was no Display. the XML page is blank.

Comment: OMG, first let me welcome you to the community. Please **note** You do not need to upload all of your code on a question. Please only post that code, that is relevant to the question. Otherwise, we will not be interested on answering them.

Comment: Does phpMyAdmin not allow you to download XML-formatted data directly anyway?

Comment: Why are you using DOM to create a new XML File and also opening an XML file to write. Check my answer for the write way

Comment: first, I think you want to load data from MySQL, instead of from phpMyAdmin. phpMyAdmin is just a web interface of MySQL client. You can also use simple save contents to a variable to generate XML instead of using `DOMDocument` (write the contents of the variables to file at the end).

Comment: Thank you for all the comments and welcome. I have come out with a new set of code. It's better than the other one, the problem now is, error : Extra content at the end of the document.

Comment: My prob is I cant let field from phpmyadmin database appear. Is there a problem in my code?

Comment: '
while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){ 
 
  $url = $objDom->createElement("item");
  $root->appendChild($url);'


is there any problem in my code?. i try to use while to display all info in my field. but, still error displays. Thank You.....

Answer (score 0):

You need to use XML headers when you are creating a XML file with PHP.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

But this is not needed when you are using `saveXML()` on the end.

Here is an example, picked out from php's manual.

```
<?php

$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0');
// we want a nice output
$doc->formatOutput = true;

$root = $doc->createElement('book');
$root = $doc->appendChild($root);

$title = $doc->createElement('title');
$title = $root->appendChild($title);

$text = $doc->createTextNode('This is the title');
$text = $title->appendChild($text);

echo "Saving all the document:\n";
echo $doc->saveXML() . "\n";

echo "Saving only the title part:\n";
echo $doc->saveXML($title);
?>
```